# Gemfire write data exception. Server crashing when writing large dataset

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I am looping through a nested object and writing it to gemfire. I get an exception while writing data.

```
java.io.EOFException: The connection has been reset while reading the header
Pool unexpected closed socket on server connection=Pooled Connection to 
as42.nj1.hcmny.com:37549: Connection[DESTROYED]). Server unreachable: could 
not connect after 1 attempts; nested exception is 
org.apache.geode.cache.client.ServerConnectivityException: Pool unexpected 
closed socket on server connection=Pooled Connection to 
as42.nj1.hcmny.com:37549: Connection[DESTROYED]). Server unreachable: could 
not connect after 1 attempts
```

there are around 1 million entries. please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem on the server. Is there anything telling in the server log? My initial guess would be an out-of-memory condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. My message lenght was too big and my socket was crashing due to the message size. i increased the socket buffer size and works ok now.